# how to save data from a multiselect with a foreach in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

I need to save the data of a multiselect that is in fact in vue.js, but when I want to save the data in the DB it shows me the following error.

> SQL: insert into `advisor_assignments` (`advisor_id`,
> `category_region_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (48,
> ["2,6,4"], 2021-06-23 17:55:38, 2021-06-23 17:55:38)

my code

```
$categorias_ids = $request->category_region_id;

        foreach($request->category_region_id as $r){
            $resep[] = $r;
            advisorAssignment::create([
                'advisor_id' => $advisor->id,
                'category_region_id' => json_encode($resep)
            ]);
        }
```

Comment: can you show full error  category_region_id in database table should be text data type .also change  'category_region_id' => json_encode($r).Also can you show advisorAssignment model.better cast that column as array

Comment: category_region_id is integer in my database. but i have tried with json_decode($resep) and it doesn't work either.

Comment: if its array then you can solve by below answer. if not then can you dd(($request->category_region_id) and post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$categorias_ids = $request->category_region_id;

    foreach($categorias_ids as $r){
        advisorAssignment::create([
            'advisor_id' => $advisor->id,
            'category_region_id' => $r,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: this way it generates this error Data truncated for column 'category_region_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `advisor_assignments` (`advisor_id`, `category_region_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (67, 2,6,4,5, 2021-06-23 20:10:11, 2021-06-23 20:10:11))

Comment: Try using explode():  $categorias_ids = explode(",", $request->category_region_id);